# razor extension method for url.content to prevent caching

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to override Url.Content to append a query string parameter to the resulting string on Url.Content.

The reason being, I have a web application that I develop, and with each release, users must clear their cache to get the new css and js. A solution for this is to append a version number to the querystring to force loading of the new version.

A working solution is as follows:

```
@{ var version = "?v=" + ViewBag.VersionNumber; }
<head>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/ux/css/base.css")@version" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Version is set in a config file so with each release, the version is updated. I would like this to be more automatic though, as currently any time a new css reference is added, we must remember to add @version to the string. An extension method the returns the path with the version number already appended would be perfect.

Also, if anyone knows who I could make changing the version number automatic with TFS check-ins or compiles that would be really useful too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static string VersionedContent(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string contentPath)
{
    string result = urlHelper.Content(contentPath);
    var versionService = Engine.IocService.GetInstance<IVersionService>();
    string tag = versionService.GetVersionTag();
    if (result.Contains('?'))
    {
        result += "&v="+tag;
    }
    else
    {
        result += "?v="+tag;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Version Service could look something like this:

```
public class VersionService : IVersionService
{
    string _versionTag;
    public VersionService()
    {
        _versionTag = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        _versionTag = _versionTag.Replace('.', '-');
    }
    #region IVersionedContentService Members

    public string GetVersionTag()
    {
        return _versionTag;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You might want to take a look at [cassette](http://getcassette.net/)

*** EDIT ***
For autom. build numbers with TFS, check out:
[automatic-assembly-file-version-numbering-in-tfs-2010](http://sgryphon.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/automatic-assembly-file-version-numbering-in-tfs-2010/)

Comment: At first glance cassette looks really useful, I'll definitely look into that more