# How to implement asp-append-version="true" to background-image property?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp-append-version

I am trying to implement the HTMLTagHelper `asp-append-version="true"` to my images.
The problem is as regards the DOM distribution, I am not assigning the attribute to an `<img>` tag but to to a `<div>` containing the image with the `background-url` property.

Moreover, the div is generated before all the DOM is loaded and I don't know if there would be a different approach of doing it.

One is obvious, change the `div` to an `img` tag, but I don't want it as my design has to remain the same.

My javascript has hitherto been like this:

```
cardHTML += '<div asp-append-version="true" class="card littleCard" style="background-image: url(/Content/Img/Especialistas/LittleCard/' + especialista.idEspecialista + '.jpg' + ')' + '" >';
cardHTML += '</div>';
```

The `asp-append-version="true"` won't work on the `div` tag.
Any ideas on how to find an approach of dealing with this  ?

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't do that. You could use something like this though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217042/razor-extension-method-for-url-content-to-prevent-caching

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will have a look and check if it can guide me to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `TagHelper` to target all elements having an inline style attribute. The following example I've tried looks working fine but if you want something more standard (similar to `ImageTagHelper`, ...), you can try looking into the base class [UrlResolutionTagHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/TagHelpers/UrlResolutionTagHelper.cs). I'm not so sure why it need to be more complicated in there in which basically you need to resolve the URL before actually processing it more. I've tried with a simple `IFileVersionProvider` and it works for relative paths as well (of course the resolved path should be at the current server's web root).

The following simple example works fine for attribute values of `HtmlString` (which is almost the usual case, some custom rendering may inject `IHtmlContent` that is not of `HtmlString`, for such complicated cases, you can refer to the source code for [UrlResolutionTagHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/TagHelpers/UrlResolutionTagHelper.cs), even copying almost the exact relevant code there is fine):

```
//target only elements having an inline style attribute
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "style")]
public class InlineStyleBackgroundElementTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    readonly IFileVersionProvider _fileVersionProvider;        
    const string BACKGROUND_URL_PATTERN = "(background(?:-image)?\\s*:[^;]*url)(\\([^)]+\\))";
    public InlineStyleBackgroundElementTagHelper(IFileVersionProvider fileVersionProvider)
    {
        _fileVersionProvider = fileVersionProvider;
    }
    //bind the asp-append-version property
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-append-version")]
    public bool AppendsVersion { get; set; }
    //inject ViewContext from the current request
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (AppendsVersion)
        {
            if (output.Attributes.TryGetAttribute("style", out var styleAttr))
            {
                //the value here should be an HtmlString, so this basically 
                //gets the raw plain string of the style attribute's value
                var inlineStyle = styleAttr.Value.ToString();
                var basePath = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathBase;
                inlineStyle = Regex.Replace(inlineStyle, BACKGROUND_URL_PATTERN, m =>
                {
                    //extract the background url contained in the inline style
                    var backgroundUrl = m.Groups[2].Value.Trim('(', ')', ' ');
                    //append the version
                    var versionedUrl = _fileVersionProvider.AddFileVersionToPath(basePath, backgroundUrl);

                    //format back the inline style with the versioned url
                    return $"{m.Groups[1]}({versionedUrl})";
                }, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("style", inlineStyle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**: just like how you use the `asp-append-version` on other built-in tag helps. (like in your example).

Comment: Hello there. I am actually trying to fetch the view Context first and therefore continue in transforming the URLs from my helper to the controller. Let's see if this can work. thanks a lot

Comment: @OrisSin I've tested the code here, it should work for your case (append file version to background url specified in the style attribute of ***any*** element, not just `div`). If you have any problem, just leave a comment or update your question and let me know, I may help you until you can adopt this solution.

Comment: so I would need to just add this class or there's something in startup because its not working here